# What is the best way to measure execution time of a function?

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking, execution-time

Obviously I can do  and `DateTime.Now.After` - `DateTime.Now.Before` but there must be something more sophisticated.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) and the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class are two that work well for finer resolution and straightforward usage.

See Also:

- [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function’s performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetimenow-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)
- [High resolution timer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163022/high-resolution-timer-in-net)
- [Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243351/environmenttickcount-vs-datetimenow)
- [What’s the best way to benchmark programs in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145103/whats-the-best-way-to-benchmark-programs-in-windows)

Answer (score 45):

I would definitely advise you to have a look at `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

And when I looked around for more about Stopwatch I found this site;

[Beware of the stopwatch](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html)

There mentioned another possibility

> Process.TotalProcessorTime

Comment: The article is updated - stopwatch has been improved.

Comment: Could you tell me the difference about `TotalProcessorTime` and `Stopwatch`? I have not search any information..

Answer (score 10):

**Use a Profiler**

Your approach will work nevertheless, but if you are looking for more sophisticated approaches. I'd suggest using a [C# Profiler](http://dotnet.jku.at/projects/Prof-It/).

The advantages they have is:

- You can even get a statement level
  breakup
- No changes required in your codebase
- Instrumentions generally have very less overhead, hence very accurate results can be obtained.

There are many available [open-source](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/profilers) as well.

Comment: There are also disadvantages to using a profiler: the information is _post factum_, instrumentation is necessary still, not suitable to be kept in production code (we may want to measure working applications, not just during development). And last: profiling may sometimes be overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Tickcount is good, however i suggest running it 100 or 1000 times, and calculating an average. 
Not only makes it more measurable - in case of really fast/short functions, but helps dealing with some one-off effects caused by the overhead.