# How can I measure the performance of a HashTable in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, list, comparison, hashtable

I am playing around with C# collections and I have decided to write a quick test to measure the performance of different collections.

My performance test goes like this:

```
int numOps= (put number here);
long start, end, numTicks1, numTicks2;
float ratio;

start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

for(int i = 0; i < numOps; i++)
{
  //add two elements to collection #1
  //remove one element from collection #1
}

end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

numTicks1 = end - start;


start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

for(int i = 0; i < numOps; i++)
{
  //add two elements to collection #2
  //remove one element from collection #2
}

end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

numTicks2 = end - start;

ratio = (float)numTicks2/(float)numTicks1;
```

Then I compare the ratio value using different Collections and different values for numOps to see how they compare.

The problem is sometimes when I use a small enough number (numOps = 500), the test results between a Hashtable and List are sporadic (in other words it's a coin flip which one is faster).  Can anyone explain why this is?

**EDIT:  Thanks everyone!  Stopwatch works like a charm.**

Comment: Just be careful what you do with them.  .net terms and conditions forbid you from publishing performance testing from the .Net framework without speaking to microsoft first.  FYI.

Comment: Probably best not to take chances.  I have removed the results and re-worded my question.

Comment: @Spence: I assume you're joking, but it says something that I'm not sure if you are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try taking a look at [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class instead of using **DateTime**

this example straight out of MSDN

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000); //your for loop
    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime, "RunTime");
```

Comment: The static method `Stopwatch.StartNew()` will both initialise a new stopwatch and start it timing, saving you having to start it manually.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by trying out a higher resolution timer.

There are quite a few questions and answers about timers already on SO.

Here's [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380919/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-execution-time-of-a-function/380927#380927) that has a list of options available to you.

In particular, check out [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to time things diagnostically is to run the code many times iteratively (so that the total time is many multiples of the resolution of whatever timing mechanism you use) and then divide by the number of iterations to get an accurate time estimate.

Stopwatch returns times that are not quantized by 15 ms, so it's obviously more appropriate for timing events.

Comment: StopWatch is built on top of high performance counter.  This queries hardware and is independent of the clock tick interrupt.  DateTime.Now is locked to 15 ms because that is when the system time is actually updated.

Comment: @Michael: try it yourself. Stopwatch and Environment.TickCount will show the same 15 ms quantization. I've done this a million times.

Comment: I just got a result of 3 ms for Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.  Verify on your system that Stopwatch.IsHighResolution is returning true.  This should be true on nearly all platforms nowadays.

Comment: @Michael: you're totally right. Either I tried this before on a system where IsHighResolution returned false, or I'm an idiot. I'll leave my answer undeleted out of shame.

Comment: I think you're right, though, that there are some random fluctations in test results, and therefore results are more accurate if you do bigger tests to time for longer (to smooth out the fluctuations).

Comment: @MusicGenesis no shame in that.

Comment: @Stan: sure there is. Read my original, unedited (and inaccurate) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to test the performance of a `Dictionary` using three different `GetHash` implementations:

```
    class TestGetHash
    {
        class First
        {
            int m_x;
        }
        class Second
        {
            static int s_allocated = 0;
            int m_allocated;
            int m_x;
            public Second()
            {
                m_allocated = ++s_allocated;
            }
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return m_allocated;
            }
        }
        class Third
        {
            int m_x;
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        internal static void test()
        {
            testT<First>(100, 1000);
            testT<First>(1000, 100);
            testT<Second>(100, 1000);
            testT<Second>(1000, 100);
            testT<Third>(100, 100);
            testT<Third>(1000, 10);
        }

        static void testT<T>(int objects, int iterations)
            where T : new()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
            {
                Dictionary<T, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<T, object>();
                for (int j = 0; j < objects; ++j)
                {
                    T t = new T();
                    dictionary.Add(t, null);
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k)
                {
                    foreach (T t in dictionary.Keys)
                    {
                        object o = dictionary[t];
                    }
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            string stopwatchMessage = string.Format("Stopwatch: {0} type, {1} objects, {2} iterations, {3} msec", typeof(T).Name, objects, iterations, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            System.Console.WriteLine(stopwatchMessage);

            stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
            {
                Dictionary<T, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<T, object>();
                for (int j = 0; j < objects; ++j)
                {
                    T t = new T();
                    dictionary.Add(t, null);
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            stopwatchMessage = string.Format("Stopwatch (fill dictionary): {0} type, {1} objects, {2} iterations, {3} msec", typeof(T).Name, objects, iterations, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            System.Console.WriteLine(stopwatchMessage);

            {
                Dictionary<T, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<T, object>();
                for (int j = 0; j < objects; ++j)
                {
                    T t = new T();
                    dictionary.Add(t, null);
                }
                stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k)
                    {
                        foreach (T t in dictionary.Keys)
                        {
                            object o = dictionary[t];
                        }
                    }
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                stopwatchMessage = string.Format("Stopwatch (read from dictionary): {0} type, {1} objects, {2} iterations, {3} msec", typeof(T).Name, objects, iterations, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                System.Console.WriteLine(stopwatchMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```