# C# replacement for PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I'm wondering if there is a ".net integrated" solution for exact time measurement (like the execution time of a function)? At the moment I'm using the PerformanceCounters from Kernel32.

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(
        out long lpPerformanceCount);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(
        out long lpFrequency);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is a high resolution framework timer class (that probably wraps that api).

Comment: It appears to be hardware and OS dependent, so it will be high resolution for windows, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Try

- [System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx)
- [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Both of these work well for finer resolution and straightforward usage.

You could also see

[What is the best way to measure execution time of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380919/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-execution-time-of-a-function)

or

[What's the best way to benchmark programs in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145103/whats-the-best-way-to-benchmark-programs-in-windows)