# Find Execution time of a Method

Tags: c#, .net

I am making an Image Steganography project for my college. I have finished the project and have kept several different algorithms for hiding data in images.

What I want to ask is that is there any way in C# through which I can find the execution/running time between two points in a program.
For example

```
//Some Code
//Code to start recording the time.
hideDataUsingAlgorithm();
//Code to stop recording and get the time of execution of the above function.
```

I want to do this to show the difference between simple(less time consuming) and more efficient but time consuming algorithms (using same data and same image). I have around 10 different algorithms for Color and GrayScale Images.

There is no multithreading so that wont be a problem. Theres simply just one main Thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring code execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376191/measuring-code-execution-time) -- This is a few days older, but [note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/), "*The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate.*"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) and the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class are two that work well for finer resolution and straightforward usage.

See Also:

1. [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function’s performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637/is-datetimenow-the-best-way-to-measure-a-functions-performance)
2. [High resolution timer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163022/high-resolution-timer-in-net)
3. [Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243351/environmenttickcount-vs-datetimenow)
4. [What’s the best way to benchmark programs in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145103/whats-the-best-way-to-benchmark-programs-in-windows)

Comment: Definitely use the `Stopwatch` class for performance testing. `TickCount` is not particularly useful for benchmarks.

Answer (score 16):

This is a useful extension method for Stopwatch:

```
public static class StopwatchExt
{
    public static string GetTimeString(this Stopwatch stopwatch, int numberofDigits = 1)
    {
        double time = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
        if (time > 1)
            return Math.Round(time, numberofDigits) + " s";
        if (time > 1e-3)
            return Math.Round(1e3 * time, numberofDigits) + " ms";
        if (time > 1e-6)
            return Math.Round(1e6 * time, numberofDigits) + " µs";
        if (time > 1e-9)
            return Math.Round(1e9 * time, numberofDigits) + " ns";
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks + " ticks";
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
//Call your method here
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.GetTimeString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
var timer = System.Diagnostics.StopWatch.StartNew();
hideDataUsingAlgorithm();
timer.Stop();
var elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare to your test method a delegate and use one of the following extension methods to execute it N times. Based on the passed format string you get printed to console:

- First call time
- Elapsed time
- Call frequency

which are all useful values. The extension methods use Stopwatch to get the highest accuracy.

```
Action acc = hideDataUsingAlgorithm;
acc.Profile(100*1000, "Method did run {runs} times in {time}s, Frequency: {frequency}");
```

To check also the startup effects you can use

```
acc.ProfileFirst(100*1000, "First call {0}s", "Method did run {runs} times in {time}s, Frequency: {frequency}");
```

This way you can easily check your methods if the method in question is not an empty method which would distort timings because the delegate invocation would be comparable to your method call. The original idea is blogged [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2008/12/16/127989.aspx).

For a deeper call time analysis a profiler is very useful too. You should try to use these as well to be able to diagnose trickier problems.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PerformanceTester
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Helper class to print out performance related data like number of runs, elapsed time and frequency
   /// </summary>
   public static class Extension
   {
       static NumberFormatInfo myNumberFormat;

       static NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat
       {
           get
           {
               if (myNumberFormat == null)
               {
                   var local = new CultureInfo("en-us", false).NumberFormat;
                   local.NumberGroupSeparator = " "; // set space as thousand separator
                   myNumberFormat = local; // make a thread safe assignment with a fully initialized variable
               }
               return myNumberFormat;
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Execute the given function and print the elapsed time to the console.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="func">Function that returns the number of iterations.</param>
       /// <param name="format">Format string which can contain {runs} or {0},{time} or {1} and {frequency} or {2}.</param>
       public static void Profile(this Func<int> func, string format)
       {

           Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
           int runs = func();  // Execute function and get number of iterations back
           watch.Stop();

           string replacedFormat = format.Replace("{runs}", "{3}")
                                         .Replace("{time}", "{4}")
                                         .Replace("{frequency}", "{5}");

           // get elapsed time back
           float sec = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0f;
           float frequency = runs / sec; // calculate frequency of the operation in question

           try
           {
               Console.WriteLine(replacedFormat,
                                   runs,  // {0} is the number of runs
                                   sec,   // {1} is the elapsed time as float
                                   frequency, // {2} is the call frequency as float
                                   runs.ToString("N0", NumberFormat),  // Expanded token {runs} is formatted with thousand separators
                                   sec.ToString("F2", NumberFormat),   // expanded token {time} is formatted as float in seconds with two digits precision
                                   frequency.ToString("N0", NumberFormat)); // expanded token {frequency} is formatted as float with thousands separators
           }
           catch (FormatException ex)
           {
               throw new FormatException(
                   String.Format("The input string format string did contain not an expected token like "+
                                 "{{runs}}/{{0}}, {{time}}/{{1}} or {{frequency}}/{{2}} or the format string " +
                                 "itself was invalid: \"{0}\"", format), ex);
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Execute the given function n-times and print the timing values (number of runs, elapsed time, call frequency)
       /// to the console window.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="func">Function to call in a for loop.</param>
       /// <param name="runs">Number of iterations.</param>
       /// <param name="format">Format string which can contain {runs} or {0},{time} or {1} and {frequency} or {2}.</param>
       public static void Profile(this Action func, int runs, string format)
       {
           Func<int> f = () =>
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
               {
                   func();
               }
               return runs;
           };
           f.Profile(format);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Call a function in a for loop n-times. The first function call will be measured independently to measure
       /// first call effects.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="func">Function to call in a loop.</param>
       /// <param name="runs">Number of iterations.</param>
       /// <param name="formatFirst">Format string for first function call performance.</param>
       /// <param name="formatOther">Format string for subsequent function call performance.</param>
       /// <remarks>
       /// The format string can contain {runs} or {0},{time} or {1} and {frequency} or {2}.
       /// </remarks>
       public static void ProfileWithFirst(this Action func, int runs, string formatFirst, string formatOther)
       {
           func.Profile(1, formatFirst);
           func.Profile(runs - 1, formatOther);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/)

Then you do:

1) Create a console project with a reference to the code you want to test.

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<YourBenchmarks>();
    }
}

public class YourBenchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public object HideDataUsingAlgorithm()
    {
        return Namespace.hideDataUsingAlgorithm(); // call the code you want to benchmark here
    }
}
```

2) Build in release and run without debugger.

3) Open the report that is in the bin/release/YourBenchmarks-report-stackoverflow.md

The report contains Median and StdDev by default. BenchmarkDotNet takes care of warmups and launches the process a number of times to give accurate statistics.

Sample report:

```
                 Method |      Median |    StdDev |
----------------------- |------------ |---------- |
 HideDataUsingAlgorithm | 252.4869 ns | 8.0261 ns |
```

For configuration read the [docs](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: what if I don't have a separate class ? I wanna bench a function found in same class.